# Number of entries by individual by day of use

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with two columns, UserName and Date. Each UserName is individual, and each Date represents an entry:

```
+----------+------------+
| UserName |    Date    |
+----------+------------+
| Albert   | 2014-11-20 |
| Albert   | 2014-11-20 |
| Albert   | 2014-11-21 |
| Albert   | 2014-11-22 |
| Barbara  | 2015-02-14 |
| Barbara  | 2015-02-14 |
| Barbara  | 2015-02-15 |
| Carlos   | 2015-05-27 |
| Carlos   | 2015-05-29 |
+----------+------------+
```

EDIT: So Albert had two entries in '2014-11-20', which is considered his first day.

My objective is to report the number of entries by **individual** by **day**, in each day. For example, If consider '2014-11-20' as Albert's day, I could translate that 'Albert' have two entries in his first day, one in his second day and one in his third day.

So, my resulting query should return:

```
+----------+------+
| UserName | Date |
+----------+------+
| Albert   |    1 |
| Albert   |    1 |
| Albert   |    2 |
| Albert   |    3 |
| Barbara  |    1 |
| Barbara  |    1 |
| Barbara  |    2 |
| Carlos   |    1 |
| Carlos   |    3 |
+----------+------+
```

EDIT: So, for Albert, for example, since '2014-11-20' is considered his first day, that date will be equivalent to 1. In this case, he has two entries in his first day, which explains '1,1'. He has one more entry, in the subsequent day. Since it's one day after the first day, that will be equivalent to 2, which explains '1,1,2'. Same logic goes for Albert's last entry, two days after the first.

I would appreciate any guideline, reference or the query itself, I need to create a report based on this information. I'm trying hard but I'm not being able to figure out this query...
Thanks for your attention!

Comment: what is your rdbms? and why isnt your result include `date' value together with the count?

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which *may* present difficulties further on.

Comment: Yes, it would really help to know what rdbms you're using. Because the solution is either to use a windowed function or to join in a subquery that returns the min date by user.

Comment: I just read more carefully and total misunderstand your request. Why your output `Albert` has `(1,1,2,3)` doesnt make sense to me what is he logic to generate that.

Comment: I believe they want to pull min date by user and then do a date difference + 1. But which method they use to accomplish that depends on what rdbms they're using.

Comment: @Strawberry: This table is a temporary table, reflect of another query. It shouldn't have any primary key because that's not compatible with it's behavior.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Each number is correspondent to a date. So 1 will be the date of the first date, and each passing day adds plus one.

I hope I have cleared every doubt until now! :)

Comment: @LucasGarcia yes, is better. But even better sample would be put more than one difference to see the result. Still waiting to know your db? SqlServer, mysql, postgres?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza SqlServer

Comment: I usually provide this links first to help new padwan learn how to ask better questions. Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
    And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 
 this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a CTE to get a row number to match first date of each group.

Then join to calculate the `DateDiff`

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da103/2)

```
with cte as (
     SELECT row_number() over (partition by [UserName] order by [Date]) as rn,
            *
     FROM users
    )
SELECT c2.rn, 
       c2.[UserName],  
       DATEDIFF(day, c1.[Date],c2.[Date]) + 1 as [Date]
from cte c1
JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.UserName = c2.UserName
 AND c1.rn <= c2.rn
WHERE c1.rn = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| rn | UserName | Date |
|----|----------|------|
|  1 |   Albert |    1 |
|  2 |   Albert |    1 |
|  3 |   Albert |    2 |
|  4 |   Albert |    3 |
|  1 |  Barbara |    1 |
|  2 |  Barbara |    1 |
|  3 |  Barbara |    2 |
|  1 |   Carlos |    1 |
|  2 |   Carlos |    3 |
```

But don't call your variable `DATE`; it is a reserved word.

Comment: @Strawberry isnt a `date` type ?

Comment: It's actual name isn't date :)

Comment: I will add an edit to the question, further explaining it.

Comment: I added some extra comments right after each table. Please, tell me if that clears the fog.

Comment: @LucasGarcia Please Check now

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'm thankful for the time you spent on this.

Comment: In a similar vein, this will also work. SELECT [UserName], DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [UserName]), [Date]) + 1 AS [Date] FROM users

Comment: Actually, I don't know this dialect. In MySQL, date IS a data type but it IS NOT a reserved word

Comment: @Strawberry Mean the same you cant call a field `DATE`, you may call it `\`DATE\`` but still would be confusing

Comment: No. While I can't comment on other RDBMSs, in MySQL date is technically fine, with or without back ticks... But I digress

Comment: @Rabbit I thought of a similar solution using GROUP BY, right after Juan's answer.

Comment: using `row_number() over (partition `  the partition works like a group by so probaly can get the same result

Answer (score -1):

You want to select the UserName and the occurences of the date grouped by username and date

```
select [UserName], COUNT([Date]) as [Date] from [table] group by [UserName], [Date]
```

Comment: That doesn't give them what they want. While they mention count in their question, what they are actually after is to translate the date into an integer representing how many days from the first date that exists for that user in the recordset.

Comment: Yes, I'm realizing now that the tittle I created was quite unhappy.